# Calling remote Servlet from GWT

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc, same-origin-policy

I am trying to call remote servlet from GWT, actually the GWT-RPC doesn't seems to work, so I am trying to do it using the RequestBuilder.

Here's the code snippet:

```
    String url = "http://some-remote-host:8888/GWTJSTest/SomeServlet?name=" + textBox.getText();
    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, url);
//              requestBuilder.setHeader("Origin", "*");
//              requestBuilder.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    try
    {
        requestBuilder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback()
        {
            public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response)
            {
                if (response.getStatusCode() == 200)
                {
                    Window.alert(response.getText());
                }else
                {
                    Window.alert(response.getText() + " : " + response.getStatusCode() + response.getStatusText());
                }
            }

            public void onError(Request arg0, Throwable arg1)
            {
                Window.alert(arg1.toString());

            }
        });
    } catch (RequestException e)
    {
        Window.alert("CATCH BLOCK: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Actually, IE8 returns the data but after a warning message, but Firefox doesn't! Why is this?

As you see, I am trying to set some request headers but no way.

Comment: You can not call another server methods, you can only only call the script's server method .. You can use proxy servlet in your server to call other server's methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added :
`<add-linker name="xs" />` to `.gwt.xml`

And then replaces `GWT-PRC` by `JsonpRequestBuilder` (transforming `JSONP` between the server and the client)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make a request to your own server and port (the same one that your GWT page is on), replace the first line with:

```
String url = "/GWTJSTest/SomeServlet?name=" + textBox.getText();
```

If you're trying to talk to a different server, or a different port on your own server, the [Same Origin Policy](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/trunk/FAQ_Server.html#What_is_the_Same_Origin_Policy,_and_how_does_it_affect_GWT?) will keep you from doing that. You'll need to proxy it from your own server.

Answer (score 0):

The remote servlet is the one that needs to set the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control) header that you have:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Alternatively you can specify just your own domain instead of `*` if you don't want other domains interacting with the remote servlet.